# Data Tables adding blank DIV and throwing Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, smarty, datatables

I am struggling to get DataTables to work without throwing an error.

This is the HTML:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/css/dataTables.tableTools.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <table width="100%" id="data-table" class="display dataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Label</th>
                <th>Receiving</th>
                <th>Label</th>
                <th width="10%">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {section name=all loop=$companyNumbers}
            <tr id="row{$companyNumbers[all].ticid}">
                <td>{$companyNumbers[all].ticno}</td>
                <td>{$companyNumbers[all].ticlabel}</td>
                <td>{$companyNumbers[all].recno}</td>
                <td>{$companyNumbers[all].reclabel}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/editNumber/{$companyNumbers[all].ticid}" data="Edit Number {$companyNumbers[all].ticno}">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {/section}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The custom.js file is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // load data tables if element found
    if (document.getElementById('data-table')) {
        $('#data-table').dataTable({
            "paging":   false,
            "ordering": true,
            "searching": true,
            "info":     false
        } );
    }

});
```

When this is run I can see that something (and I am assuming it is DataTables is adding a blank DIV into the markup as follows and I cannot see the usual code that DataTables inserts:

```
<body>
    <div>
    <div></div><table width="100%" id="data-table" class="display dataTable no-footer">
    <thead>
```

And I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
jquery.dataTables.js:2786
```

I read on the DataTables FAQ that maybe this line:

```
        $('#data-table').dataTable({
```

should be:

```
        $('#data-table').DataTable({
```

But that makes no difference.

I have tried everything that I can think of but nothing can resolve the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Anything look odd in the generated HTML after php has done its thing? It looks fine to me on first glance. I guess dig out the offending line in datatables.js and post the code in and around that. Creating a wrapper div is standard datatables, looks like it's encountering problems moving the table inside it. What version of jquery are you running?

Comment: @ChrisV must have been the version of jQuery because when I changed it to point to v2.1.3 it magically worked. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the version of jQuery. I changed my locally hosted version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

to a CDN version

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And DataTables started to work.